# How can get a folder name in an MSBuild Project file?

Tags: msbuild

In an MSBuild Project file, I want to take the following variable:

```
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
```

Which is equal to:

```
c:\projects\myproject\branches\changenumber\soapservice
```

And create this variable:

```
$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryName)
```

Setting it to this:

```
changenumber
```

I want to do something like the following in a MSBuild Project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LinqToXsdBinDir Condition="'$(LinqToXsdBinDir)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
    <MSBuildProjectParentDirectoryName Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryName)' == ''">Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectory($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</MSBuildProjectParentDirectoryName>
    ***SNIP***
  </PropertyGroup>
  ***SNIP***
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost/ThisSoft/$(MSBuildProjectParentDirectoryName)/LayerName</IISUrl>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

How can I set an MSBuild variable to be the equivalent of:

```
string MSBuildProjectDirectory = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(bob));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you take a common branch property file, say "Branch.Props" and you place it at c:\projects\myproject\branches\changenumber\branch.props.
Then you add common msbuild properties to this files, such as:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LinqToXsdBinDir Condition="'$(LinqToXsdBinDir)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)..\LinqToXsd</LinqToXsdBinDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then because you appreciate MsBuild reserved names, you create a new property in all of your solution projects that isn't prefixed with "MsBuild":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BranchRoot>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) ,Branch.Props))</BranchRoot>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(BranchRoot)\Branch.props" />
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sadly it seems that you can't actually make a dynamic IISUrl, the string gets used as is. But still very useful to learn about all those functions that are build into MSBuild.